# How can I access fetched data with multiple layers?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I need help trying to access the data the is fetched from an API? The only thing I can do is `game.results` which I show lower. Everything else I try just outputs "undefined". I'm not sure what else to try that is why I am asking because I have run out of ways to fix this.

```js
function showGames()
{
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '<KEY>'
    }
  };
  let url = 'https://sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com/games?league=NBA&date=2022-04-28';
  fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const games = data;
      let game = games;
      let result = `<h2> NBA GAMES</h2>`;
      console.log(game.results);
      for(let i = 0; i < game.length; i++)
      {
        thisGame = game[i];
        result += `
          <div>
            <h1>${game.results.summary}</h1>
          </div>
              `;
      }
      document.getElementById("games").innerHTML = result;
    });
}

window.onload=showGames();
```

This is what one of the outputs of `data.results` looks like. I'm not sure how I can access the data in here like summary. I've tried using `game.results.summary` but it just outputs undefined.

```json
[ { schedule: { date: '2022-04-28T23:00:00.000Z', tbaTime: false },
    summary: 'Philadelphia 76ers @ Toronto Raptors',
    details: 
     { league: 'NBA',
       seasonType: 'postseason',
       season: 2021,
       conferenceGame: true,
       divisionGame: true },
    status: 'final',
    teams: { away: [Object], home: [Object] },
    lastUpdated: '2022-04-29T01:38:41.138Z',
    gameId: 284279,
    venue: 
     { name: 'Scotiabank Arena',
       city: 'Toronto',
       state: 'ON',
       neutralSite: false },
    odds: [ [Object] ],
    scoreboard: 
     { score: [Object],
       currentPeriod: 4,
       periodTimeRemaining: '0:00' } },
```

Comment: res.json() will be return an array, so the `console.log(game.results)` won't return anything.

Comment: the example under the code is what is sent to the console from console.log(game.results)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This statement in your loop:

```
game = game[i];
```

overwrites the array `game` and breaks the whole thing. You need a variable to use in the loop that is separate from the `game` array:

```
let thisGame = game[i];
```

Comment: I fixed this but the problem is still the same.